# strcpy function not working properly

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcpy, strlen

Please consider the below code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void main()
{
    char a[6], b[6];

    strcpy(a,"rajeev");
    printf("print A:");
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
    {
         printf("%c",a[i]);
    }

    strcpy(b,a);
    printf("print B:");
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(b);i++)
    {
        printf("%c",b[i]);
    }

    printf("trying to print A again");
    for(int i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
    {
        printf("%c",a[i]);
    }
```

While running this program,in the "trying to print A again" section prints nothing, and the `strlen(a)` will be 0.  That means the source array will be empty.

Can you please help me to understand the phenomena behind this?
But, change the declaration of `a[6]` to `char* a=malloc(6)` works properly.

Comment: arrays are one element short of being strings here.

Comment: `strlen(a)` would be UB..most likely.

Comment: If you try `"raj"` instead of `"rajeev"`, it will work. This is because you did not count null terminator.

Comment: `strcpy(a,"rajeev");` is UB, as it is accessing past the allocated memory.

Comment: Formatting/indentation:(

Comment: 'a[6],b[6]' - bean-counting error:(

Comment: sorry i cant get the term UB. can you please help me to get it.

Comment: [Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

Comment: Actually my doubt is why the Array "a" is empty after implementing the strcpy(b,a)?

Comment: Any reasoning about the program semantics won't be valid as long as it's behavior is undefined.

Comment: but, if am using char *a=malloc(6) instead of a[6] it work properly.

Comment: That is an unlucky illusion. You still need 7 bytes. 6 for the characters and 1 for the string terminator.

Comment: An analogy: you book 6 seats on a train for your party of 7. You all sit down in reserved seats, but nobody turns up to claim the seat you didn't book before you reach the destination. That is lucky, but in C is unlucky because you imagine you can continue to use unbooked seats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string literal `"rajeev"` has type char[7]. That is it has the static storage duration and is stored as an array initialized like

```
char unnamed[] = { 'r', 'a', 'j', 'e', 'e', 'v', '\0' };
```

So if you are going to copy its content as a string using the function `strcpy` you need provide enough memory in the destination array. For example

```
char a[7], b[7];

strcpy(a,"rajeev");
printf("print A:");
for ( size_t i = 0, n = strlen( a ); i < n; i++ )
{
     printf("%c",a[i]);
}

//... and so on
```

Take into account that the function `strlen` counts characters until the terminating zero is encountered. So if a character array does not include this character then the function's behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Your arrays aren't being enough to hold the string you're trying to store.

String in C are defined as a *null terminated sequence of characters*, meaning that a proper string has a null byte at the end.

Your arrays can hold 6 bytes, but your string `"rajeev"` needs 7 bytes (6 for the letters and one for the implicit null byte at the end.  As a result, you write past the end of the array.  Writing outside the bounds of an array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

In the case where you dynamically allocate memory, you are again invoking undefined behavior.  In this case it *appears* to work properly.  That's one of the ways undefined behavior can manifest.

To fix this, your arrays need to be at least 7 elements long:

```
char a[7], b[7];
```

Answer (score 1):

The array you defined  `char a[6], b[6]` don't have enough space to fit the string you are trying to store.

Kindly remember that every array in C has a null byte `\0` at the end.

You can fix it by giving enough space to the array:

```
char a[7], b[7];
```

Comment: null byte is `\0` not `"/0"`

Comment: yeah. my bad :D. Updated! Thanks for info

Answer (score 0):

a & b are too small and because a is just after b the first byte of it is zero after the strcpy execution.

malloc has worked because this chunk of memory was allocated in the other place in the memory. But it was just accidental, as you wrote more memory than you have allocated.

Any access to the memory which was not somehow allocated is illegal and it is an UB.

Comment: Your are onto something but the order of `a` and `b` (on the stack, if there is a stack) is undefined.

Comment: I guessed it from the program results :) to explain why first byte of a became 0.

Comment: Better to focus on improving the code than trying to explain *undefined behaviour*. Can you convert your "comment" to a proper answer?

Comment: Sometimes when you see the result it is easier to understand the UB. I wrote that tables a & b are too small to accommodate the string

Comment: So what is the proper answer, the solution?

Comment: @Weather Vane - read 5 first words of the answer and there is the sollution. Hint - if something is too small ..... ?? If you have too small trousers you need to buy ..........

Comment: Sorry, this is a comment, not answer, which should have provided a solution, instead of speculating about UB.

Comment: @Weather Vane It is the answer for the question asked: **_'Can you please help me to understand the phenomena behind this?'_**. He did not ask for the solution. Knowing it quite intelligent human being cam work out the solution himself.

Comment: Sorry my DV because you refused to be prompted into providing a good answer. If you can edit the answer I will retract the DV.

Comment: @ Weather Vane - Who cares?

Comment: Well, if you care about providing useful answers you would also have addressed the OP's question about why `malloc` worked.